# How do i get value from dictionary when there are more values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've searched on the internet for how to make dictionary with multiple values and ive found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709625/c-sharp-dictionary-with-multiple-values-per-key?rq=1)

```
class MyType
{
public string SomeVal1{ get; set; }
public string SomeVal2{ get; set; }
public bool SomeVal3{ get; set; }
public bool SomeVal4{ get; set; }
public int SomeVal5{ get; set; }
public bool SomeVal6{ get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var someDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();
```

and

```
someDictionary.Add( 1, 
                    new MyType{
                        SomeVal1 = "foo",
                        SomeVal2 = "bar",
                        SomeVal3 = true,
                        SomeVal4 = false,
                        SomeVal5 = 42,
                        SomeVal6 = true
                    });
```

My question is, how do i get specific value from that dictionary? For example, how do i get int 42?

Comment: please use tuple for this see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: `someDictionary[1].SomeVal5` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an object of your type MyType to store the value of the dictionary.

```
    MyType _myType = someDictionary[1]
    _myType.SomeVal1 will be equal to "foo"
```

If you just want to store a bunch of MyType objects, you can use List then you don't have to explicitly add indexers, but you can still access it by an index.

Comment: "don't have to explicitly add indexers, but you can still access it by an index." I have some vague idea about what you want to say. Is it "you don´t have a **key** as in a `dictionary`, however you have an **index**"?

Comment: Yes, with arrays you have to specify the index (location) of the value you want to store, with List<T> you don't. But you can still access it the same way, first item in the list will be accessible List[0], and first item in the array will be accessible by Array[0].